# Using UITextInputPasswordRules in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, passwords, swiftui

I want to use the UITextInputPasswordRules in my SwiftUI Code for validating a password from the user.

The **Swift** code would look like this Codesnippet:

```
let newPasswordTextField = UITextField()
newPasswordTextField.passwordRules = UITextInputPasswordRules(descriptor: "required: lower; required: upper; required: digit; required: special; allowed: unicode; minlength: 10;")
```

My **SwiftUI** Code looks like that, so far:

```
struct CustomPasswordTextField: View {
    let passwordRuleDescription: String = "required: lower; required: upper; required: digit; required: special; allowed: unicode; minlength: 10;"
    var placeholder: Text
    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if text.isEmpty { placeholder }
            SecureField("", text: $text)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I apply the passwordRuleDescription to the `SecureField(", text: $text")`?

Comment: You can't. It's not ported to SwiftUI (yet). Use a `UIViewRepresentable` for the `UITextField` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
struct CustomPasswordTextField: View {
    var placeholder: String
    @Binding var text: String

    init(placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self._text = text

        let passwordRuleDescription: String = "required: lower; required: upper; required: digit; required: special; allowed: unicode; minlength: 10;"
        
        UITextField.appearance().passwordRules = UITextInputPasswordRules(descriptor: passwordRuleDescription)
    }
    // body implementation etc...
}
```

Comment: It worked in my app. Thanks